# Post modified but nothing has changed

Tags: bug, questions, edits, deleted-answers

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915538/knockoujs-onclick-button-how-to-focus-and-clear-the-input-field-text), which is in one of the tags I follow was back on top of the [knockout "active" list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knockout.js?sort=active&pageSize=30) this morning, stating it was modified:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

When I navigate to the question though, I can't see any edits or new answers. Did someone answer and delete their answer, perhaps a 10K user can check that? If so, should that action cause the modified time to change. If not, does anybody have an idea what has caused the modified time to be updated?

Comment: Related feature request: [Updates to deleted answers should not bump a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271978/updates-to-deleted-answers-should-not-bump-a-question)

Comment: Maybe the line endings changed.

Comment: @trysis the cause is in the answer below.

Comment: apparently some people can't take a (bad) joke.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An answer that was deleted 2 days ago (2014-09-19 12:42:54) was updated 2 hours ago (2014-09-22 07:07:10).

That answer is still deleted, and in fact, was never undeleted.

This *does* update the "modified" timestamp of the question. Whether modifying a deleted post should update the "modified" time of the question is certainly a case for discussion. I'd edge towards "no". Infact, I'd go as far to say that modifying a post, *then* deleting it, should also have no impact on the "modified" time of a question.

However, this "modified" behavior has been in place for as long as I can remember; it's not like it's a recent regression in behavior.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. It does seem odd that such an action would draw attention to a post when there's nothing to see... unless you're 10K+

Comment: @Tanner: Completely agree with you there. This sequence of events (modified posts being deleted/ being modified whilst deleted) is a common cause of confusion on meta for < 10k users; because like you said, they navigate to the post and see nothing's changed.

Comment: Sometimes users will intentionally delete a bad answer or question until they get a chance to fix it to their satisfaction (however many edits and days that takes), then undelete it. That prevents other people (except 10k+ users, who should know better) from being misled by a bad answer or trying to answer a bad question, which would arguably be worse than confusing people…

Comment: Often this is simply spam - a spam answer is posted to a question, it's later deleted; so Community is listed as the last updater, as of the time the answer was deleted.

Comment: @abarnert: I wasn't suggesting for a second that we should block people from deleting/ editing deleted posts; we should just stop updating the "modified" time in this scenario... either for everyone, or just for < 10ks.

Comment: @Matt I'm wondering if this should be retagged as a feature request to prevent that behaviour as it seems like it's by design that a deleted post modifies the last updated time? Or should it be a new linked question?

Comment: Sounds like a nice tool to bump your question to the frontpage. Answer, delete answer, and keep changing the deleted answer...

Comment: @Tanner: Hummm. I would edge towards a new question. Don't quote me on it though :P.

Comment: @Matt feature requested, cheers