# Updates to deleted answers should not bump a question

Tags: feature-request, edits, deleted-answers, last-activity

After asking this question: **[Post modified but nothing has changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271847/post-modified-but-nothing-has-changed)**

I found out that if a user updates a deleted answer, it bumps the question as it updates the last modified time.

For users under 10k watching an active queue, it would rise to the top but when opening the question there is nothing new to see. I'd argue that it shouldn't rise to the top for any user as it's deleted content.

I guess this happens as some users may delete an answer to improve it, but the improvements might happen iteratively, so there might be many updates that keep bumping a question to the top of the pile with nothing new to see.

There are 2 options as far as I can see with this feature request:

1. All updates to deleted answers have no impact on the last modified time of the question
2. Updates to deleted answers update the last modified time of the deleted answer, but these updates are only visible to 10k users

Option 2 would be trickier as the `Posts` table has a `LastActivityDate` that can obviously only hold a single value, so there would need to be an additional calculation based on user rep being under/over 10k and the `LastActivityDate` on the deleted answer.

Of course, option 3 is leave it as it is.

**UPDATE May 2016:**

I've just tested this by editing a deleted answer of mine and this behavior still persists. The below question, hadn't been active for 8 days:

[Mark duplicate data with DUP in SQL server with multiple column comparision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025110/mark-duplicate-data-with-dup-in-sql-server-with-multiple-column-comparision)

I made an edit to my deleted answer (which is still deleted) and it bumped the question to the top of the active queue, and as previously stated, no updates are visible for users under 10K who can't see deleted answers.

**UPDATE November 2016**

This is still an issue that hasn't had a response.

[@Matt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt)'s [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271850/57475) on the related post confirms the problem and suggests  what I am requesting here:

> An answer that was deleted 2 days ago (2014-09-19 12:42:54) was updated 2 hours ago (2014-09-22 07:07:10).
>
> That answer is still deleted, and in fact, was never undeleted.
>
> This does update the "modified" timestamp of the question. Whether modifying a deleted post should update the "modified" time of the question is certainly a case for discussion. I'd edge towards "no". Infact, I'd go as far to say that modifying a post, then deleting it, should also have no impact on the "modified" time of a question.

Also, there is a potential for abusing this to bump a question as [noted in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271847/post-modified-but-nothing-has-changed#comment96934_271850) by [@PlasmaHH](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/833362/plasmahh):

> Sounds like a nice tool to bump your question to the frontpage. Answer, delete answer, and keep changing the deleted answer...

I was also wondering if making serial edits to a deleted answer would flag an answer / user for this behavior, see this related post that indicates that serial edits raise an automatic flag:

[How should I handle serial editing of an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290447/how-should-i-handle-serial-editing-of-an-answer)

And [@Brad-Larson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson)'s [response](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290447/how-should-i-handle-serial-editing-of-an-answer#comment177930_290448):

> We do get automatic system flags for these now. That answer triggered one, and a moderator had looked into it at the time and thought the editing had stopped. I've given them a gentle warning about this.

Comment: Would the bump happen when the post is undeleted?

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, that's a valid case as there is something visibly modified for all users to see.

Comment: @Tanner That's why a mod flag is raised when a post is edited more than a certain number of times; so that continued edits with the goal of bumping the post can be handled by a mod.

Comment: @Servy Good to know, I didn't realise that happened.

Comment: Loophole, good feature-request

Comment: Still not fixed. Irritating when you track a tag by RSS and it shows up in your feed.

Comment: Just came across this in [tag:completable-future]. I suppose that's what happened on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540466/spring-promoting-request-scoped-bean-to-child-threads-httpservletrequest) but I have no way to check myself.

Comment: @DidierL just checked, somebody posted an answer yesterday which is now deleted, hence the activity date was bumped.