# How should I handle serial editing of an answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I came across an **answer** today with 25 edits in a period of approximately 2 days. Here's a partial summary of the edits:

[image: Partial edit summary]

A few of the 25 edits made what I'd classify as substantial changes, but most seem to be attempts to bump the post by adding and removing spaces for no reason.

As far as I know, there is a method to detect numerous minor edits. Would this be picked up and the user be warned?

Should I post a comment to tell the user that they should refrain from doing this?

Or if neither of the above, should this be a job for a moderator via a custom flag?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flag the post and let a mod deal with it; they're the only ones with the tools to address such a problem.

Comment: Isn't there some magic automatic process to detect these types of edit though? That's why I didn't flag it initially.

Comment: @Tanner It was removed some time ago because of the false positive rate.

Comment: cheers, have flagged the answer.

Comment: @Tanner - We do get automatic system flags for these now. That answer triggered one, and a moderator had looked into it at the time and thought the editing had stopped. I've given them a gentle warning about this.

Comment: @BradLarson thanks, so the process for detecting serial edits has been reinstated now?

Comment: @Tanner - The automatic conversion to wiki after a certain number of edits was replaced with a system-generated flag. That's been active since the conversion to wiki was turned off. We've been acting on these since then, although they're usually false positives.