# What is the last action?

Tags: discussion, last-activity

In the question [Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/4519059), today I see the active value is `today`, so I click the [`[today]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/29942941?lastactivity) and it moves to [no-where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/29942941#29942941).

I want to know *Why* and *When* clicking on `today` moves to no-where?

**Edit :**

I found the [list of activities](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/308638/list-of-activities) And the fedorqui answer to the list:

```
Id | Name                             | No-Where
---+---------------------------- ... -+----------------
1  | Initial Title                    | 
2  | Initial Body                     | 
3  | Initial Tags                     | 
4  | Edit Title                       | 
5  | Edit Body                        | 
6  | Edit Tags                        | 
7  | Rollback Title                   | 
8  | Rollback Body                    | 
9  | Rollback Tags                    | 
10 | Post Closed                      | 
11 | Post Reopened                    | 
12 | Post Deleted                     | for reputation < 10K
13 | Post Undeleted                   | 
14 | Post Locked                      | 
15 | Post Unlocked                    | 
16 | Community Owned                  | 
17 | Post Migrated                    | 
18 | Question Merged                  | 
19 | Question Protected               | 
20 | Question Unprotected             | 
22 | Question Unmerged                | 
24 | Suggested Edit Applied           | 
25 | Post Tweeted                     | 
31 | Discussion moved to chat         | 
33 | Post Notice Added                | 
34 | Post Notice Removed              | 
35 | Post Migrated Away               | 
36 | Post Migrated Here               | 
37 | Post Merge Source                | 
38 | Post Merge Destination           |
```

Comment: related feature request, that edits to deleted posts should not affect the last modified time: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271978/updates-to-deleted-answers-should-not-bump-a-question

Comment: @Tanner my question is not just about deleted posts, If in list of activities the only no-where is that I highlighted, note that ;).

Answer (score 3):

This is because it points to a deleted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29942941

If you have >10K reputation you can see it. For those who don't, I have taken a screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, And is this the only situation of moving to no-where?

Comment: Checking [What does active mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242868/209901) I see that _"Active" shows when the post was last active. Active means that it has a change: an edit, an answer, an edit to an answer, bumped by Community♦ etc..._ So I can just imagine this happening when any of these was done on a deleted answer.