# Sort answers by "active" doesn't work?

Tags: discussion, sorting

[TFS "Assign To" is showing too many users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771030/tfs-assign-to-is-showing-too-many-users?answertab=active#tab-top)

When I hover over "active" it says "Answers with the latest activity first".  However, when selected, an answer that has a comment from an hour ago is still 3rd in the list.

Am I just misunderstanding what this means?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you're mistaken. The comments on answered aren't considered to be activity.

For answers, new activity is 1) when they're posted 2) when they're edited.

Do note that the accepted answers, if not posted by the OP of the question, are still floating top.

Comment: Thanks, though personally I would consider comments "Activity" on an answer.  This seems more like the tab should say "Updated"

Comment: @Devil Activity for the answers is defined as something changing it, though I'd agree the comments are also some sort of activity, but secondary.

Comment: also worth noting that [edits to deleted answers also bump posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271978/updates-to-deleted-answers-should-not-bump-a-question) but only 10k+ users will see them.