# Filter answers by newest

Tags: feature-request

Right now, it seems you can only filter answers by active, oldest or votes. Is it possible to filter by `newest`?

This would be very handy on older questions, with a large number of (high-voted) answers, but where new solutions, techniques are popping up. I would be interested in the recent, (less-voted) answers containing the 'new kid on the block solution'. Filtering on `active` does not do the job, because comments on answers are taken into account too.

Comment: Do you intend for this to continue to be a feature-request, or are you satisfied with how the system currently works, after having learned that your assumptions were incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Filtering on active does not do the job, because comments on answers are taken into account too.

No, comments are not taken into account.

As nicael said in response to [Sort answers by "active" doesn't work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314429/sort-answers-by-active-doesnt-work):

> The comments on answered aren't considered to be activity.
>
> For answers, new activity is 1) when they're posted 2) when they're
>   edited.

Comment: comments may not be taken into account, but [edits to deleted answers are](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271978/updates-to-deleted-answers-should-not-bump-a-question)

Comment: I agree with the 'sense' of the "active" sorting option. But, adding a "newest" sort option will allow new posts to gain currency (and reputation) for the answerers, who would otherwise have little incentive to post a better answer, as the probability of finding a latest answer, if the reader wants it, is very low for the current configuration, compared to the proposed "newest" sort option.