# Upvote on a yesterday's question a few minutes after my answer

Tags: discussion, answers, upvotes, notifications, bump

After the OP commented back, making an answer possible, I finally answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924635/wheres-the-header-files-information-in-the-compiled-file-assemble-file).

The question was asked yesterday, so it was no longer among the "active" answers, so I was not hoping getting much attention apart from the OP.

I was pleasantly surprised to receive one upvote after a few minutes, even if the OP has not enough reputation to upvote. So it cannot be him. Also, the question was not bumped / made more visible, because I answered it (to my knowledge, hence my question).

I was wondering how the upvoter could be so swiftly advised of my answer? Was it just because he/she had a remaining open tab on the question from the moment it was posted? Or something else?

Comment: Look behind you ... that's right ... we know ...

Comment: @Bart what do you mean?

Comment: Terrible terrible joke. That we get to respond so fast because "we" have been following you all along.

Comment: @Bart it's not a joke, we take our stalking very seriously!

Comment: @Bart that's good. I'll destroy my hard drive now.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No worries, we have lots of backups.

Comment: haha I guess you cannot get upvotes AND fun :)

Comment: We hat fun ... and it is not Friday ...

Comment: @rene: _hat fun?_ You mean Winterbash? :p

Comment: @honk My start page is http://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/  .... can't wait ...

Comment: @rene: I guess you just like watching pandas having fun ;)

Comment: mildly related, that [updates to deleted answers also bump posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271978/updates-to-deleted-answers-should-not-bump-a-question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Posting an answer counts as "activity" on a question, so it does in fact change when it was considered "last active".

Comment: sorry for that dumb question. I wasn't using "active" but "newest". Interesting. The information is well worth all the downvotes :)