# "Active" does not change if an answer is deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

A [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588384/how-to-define-an-enum-with-string-value/39658838#39658838) has been posted to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8588384/2279200) question 3 days ago. This answer was deleted at some point today.

The "Active" indicator was not updated, which is a bit misleading. I was expecting that the "Active" will also reset to the previous value (before adding the new answer)

[image]

- Is this a bug?
- Is this by design? (why?)
- [Should we blame cache](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Related: [Post modified but nothing has changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271847/2279200)

Comment: Pretty hard to guess why you'd prefer a question to be re-activated when there is *less* to see.  The machine is doing the sensible thing.

Comment: @HansPassant, I was meaning the exact opposite thing. See my update,

Comment: I agree this is somewhat confusing when you don't have the necessary rep to see deleted answers, since you just end up at the top of the page instead of at the location of the answer.

Comment: It would be nice if it did something like Documentation does, where it would say "This answer was deleted". Maybe we can't have the link "See this question with the answer before it was deleted" when <10K, but it could help to know that's why it was modified.

Comment: This is by design.  If you look at the URL you will see numbers at the end.  That is the number post id that the active link links to.  Since it goes nowhere that means you do not have the permission to see it.